# .toggle() issue with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form wherein there is a question where you can select multiple answer including Others by ticking the checkboxes. Then you tick others, it's suppose to show a textbox and when unticked, it should hide the textbox again.

What happens is when I untick it, yes it hides but the validation error still pops up. I'm not sure what's causing it. In other words, despite the fact that it is hidden, it is still validating.

Here's my javascript:

```
$("input[name = 'production-up']").change(function () {
    //check if the selected option is others
    if (this.value === "other") {
        //toggle textbox visibility
        $("#productionUpOther").toggle();
    }
});
```

and my HTML:

```
<span id='productionUp' class='level'>
                <p>Production - Reasons why it is up. Click as many as apply.</p>
                <input type='checkbox' name='production-up' value='Increase in demand' required>Increase in demand <br/>
                <input type='checkbox' name='production-up' value='Expected increase in demand'>Expected increase in demand <br/> 
                <input type='checkbox' name='production-up' value='Fullfillment of past orders'>Fulfillment of past orders <br/>
                <input type='checkbox' name='production-up' value='Increased marketing activity'>Increased marketing activity <br/>
                <input id="other" type="checkbox" name="production-up" value='other' />Other
                <input id='productionUpOther' name='other-production-up' type='text' required/>
            </span>
```

Be informed that this is just a part of my code. Any ideas on how to do something about this?!

Here you can that I ticked `other`
[image: This is what it looks like:]

But when I untick it and press Next it still needs to be validated.

[image]

Comment: @Canal  have you seen my answer

Comment: I did try it but nothing happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$("input[name = 'production-up']").change(function () {
    //check if the selected option is others
    if (this.value === "other") {
        //toggle textbox visibility
        $("#productionUpOther").toggle();
        if (this.checked) {
           $("#productionUpOther").attr('required','1');
        } else {
           $("#productionUpOther").removeAttr('required');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey man, really... Thanks! Couldn't be any better than this.

Thanks guys!

Comment: I was waiting for 5 minutes. Haha. Thanks again. Other answers work too but this seems to be straight forward.

Comment: How about in radio button? I can't make this work with radio button. :(

Answer (score 2):

What you wanna do is disabling the text field 'other'. So in this case, I would use the 'disabled' property and then hide the field using CSS.

An example could be :

**JS**

```
$("#productionUpOther").prop('disabled', true);
$("input[name = 'production-up']").change(function () {
    var hasTheFieldToBeEnabled = this.value === "other" && this.checked;
    $("#productionUpOther").prop('disabled', !hasTheFieldToBeEnabled);
});
```

**CSS**

```
:disabled
{
    display: none;
}
```

Here, all the disabled fields are hidden... But CSS is your friend if that's not what you want ^^

**/!\** Careful: IE <8 doesn't support ':disabled', so if you want to support IE 8, you should add a class to the input when disabling it

Comment: you're welcome ^^ I think removing the 'required' prop is not really the aim here

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$("#productionUpOther").hide();
    $("input[name = 'production-up']").change(function () {
        //check if the selected option is others
        if (this.value === "other"  && this.checked) {
            //toggle textbox visibility
            $("#productionUpOther").show();
        }
        else{
            $("#productionUpOther").hide();
        }
    });
```

see [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fx2QJ/)

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use [**ID Selector ("#ID")**](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

```
$("input#other").change(function () {
     $("#productionUpOther").toggle(this.checked);
     $("#productionUpOther").prop('required', this.checked);
});
```